# python mongoenqine querying documents

Tags: python, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am querying 2 collections from mongodb. I am querying one collection that has a field called 'quiz_id'. I want to search for the value of this field (e.g. the first quiz_id value is 'M7001'). In the second collection, I want to search for value of the 'quiz_id' (it's a score from a quiz taken from 0 to 10) from the first query which is a key and return the value. Here is what I have:

```
quizzes = Topic_maths.objects.order_by('quiz_id')
quiz_chk = User.objects.filter(username=current_user)

for quiz_id in quizzes:
    print (quiz_id.quiz_id)
    key = quiz_id.quiz_id
    if key in quiz_chk:
        print ("score: ", key.quiz_id)
    else:
        print ("no score")
```

So the first part 'print (quiz_id.quiz_id)' prints each of the quiz id numbers ok. but I can't figure out how to search the mongo queryset returned for the key. For information:

```
print (quiz_id.quiz_id)
<class 'flask_mongoengine.BaseQuerySet'>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quiz_chk` requires additional iteration:

`[q['quiz_id'] for q in quiz_chk]`

which would make entire code look like that:

```
from mongoengine import *

connect('test')


class TopicMaths(Document):
    quiz_id = StringField()


class User(Document):
    username = StringField()
    quiz_id = StringField()


current_user = 'Bob'

quizzes = TopicMaths.objects.order_by('quiz_id')
quiz_chk = User.objects.filter(username=current_user)

for quiz_id in quizzes:
    print(quiz_id.quiz_id)
    key = quiz_id.quiz_id
    if key in [q['quiz_id'] for q in quiz_chk]:
        print("score: ", key)
    else:
        print("no score")
```

Output:

```
M7001
no score
M7002
score:  M7002
M7003
no score
```